# Is it correct to make a call to another Spring microservice inside a filter?

Tags: spring, filter, microservices

I built a Spring authentication microservice that takes care of authenticating each REST request. The authentication mechanism has been built using `JWT`. Each request should present an `Authentication: Bearer` header.

I also built a gateway microservice that exposes some of the API of the back end microservices. Each request to the gateway should be authenticated. I was thinking about implementing a `OncePerRequestFilter`, from which I could call the authentication microservice.

```java
@Component
public class AuthFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    @Autowired
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        // User restTemplate to call the authentication microservice and authenticate the request.
    }
}
```

My question is probably a little too broad, but I wanted to try anyway.

Are there any issues on making a HTTP request inside a Spring filter? Could this lead to hangs or anything in some edge cases or is it just a poor design?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is okay to call the external service inside a Filter. Spring Security also often does it in various cases (e.g. authenticate against LDAP, get JWK to verify JWT signature etc.) It may not call the external service directly inside the filter , but the filter will delegate to other object to call the external service. But the idea is the same, just make sure that you handle the case when the external service is not available such as setting a reasonable timeout on the HTTP request when calling the external service. Consider it as fail if it cannot receive the response from the external service after timeout.

P.S. Look like you are implementing your own authorization flow. If your authentication service support OAuth2 , you can consider to try Spring Security 5 's OAuth2 support which may make your life easier.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with you that this approach is contradictory.
I see 2 main constraints in this approach:

- this filter in request scope, so you can face with connection/read timeout;
- more complex error handling (nested structure requires more accuracy in that).

If you can avoid these constraints, you can use this approach: RestTemplate is synchronous and blocking, so your filter will wait for results of RestTemplate call. With WebClient, such task could be unachievable.

Obviously that this implementation contradicts to SOLID, so better change your design/architecture.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Could you please argument a little more about SOLID principles violation?

Comment: Single Responsibility: the filter class does the work a little beyond his competence - we can discuss about that but my main argument - the filter call external resources to check not a request/response but data which we can get with request/response.

Interface Sergregation: you try to implement much more functionality in filter class than it should do.

Dependency Inversion: very indirectly, but the violation is visible on the basis of the definition of principle - with external requests this filter becomes very hardcoded. I repeat - it's very indirectly, only based on the theory.

Comment: Would adding a service only responsible to making the call solve these problems?

Answer (score 0):

It's a general practice to make HTTP calls from one microservice to another.

When dealing with authentication in REST API using JWT tokens it's a common practice to load cryptographic keys from a well known URL (https://YOUR_DOMAIN/.well-known/jwks.json) as JSON Web Key Set (JWKS).

According to **SOLID** principles, it's a good practice to create a dedicated class (Spring service) responsible for calling another service instead of injecting `RestTemplate` directly into the `Filter`.

The less responsibilities class has, the easier (less error-prone) it is to make changes to it in the future and cover code with unit tests. When all the logic is located in a single class, you have a lot of test cases and complicated mocking. When class has a single responsibility and calls another classes, it's easy to mock these classes and test only this single responsibility.

When a microservice calls another microservice via REST API, there are a few aspects that should be taken into account:

- **Failover** - have multiple instances of the microservice to tolerate failure if a single instance
- **Scalability** - dynamically start more microservice instances to handle growing load
- **Load balancing** - route requests to different instances of the microservice
- **Service discovery** - allow microservices to find each other by logical name instead of hard-coding host and port values
- **Timeouts** - drop a request to a downstream microservice after exceeding timeout instead of waiting for the response forever
- **Retries** - retry failed requests to a downstream microservice
- **Circuit breaker** - prevent network or service failure from cascading to other services

These aspects are covered by **Kubernetes** + **Istio** or **Spring Cloud** stack.

If synchronous REST API calls between microservices are replaced with **asynchronous messaging** then almost all of these aspects are not so important.

For example, service A, instead of calling service B via REST API, subscribes on events emitted by service B to a Kafka topic. Every time event occurs, service A receives notification and persists the required data in own DB.

Such approach allows to achieve maximum decoupling between services but leads to eventual consistency. It means, it doesn't suit authentication and other strongly consistent cases. E.g. checking account balance is strongly consistent and should be done using synchronous call.